# Adding "Resources" to VS2013 Project

Tags: visual-studio-2013, resources

I've written a VS2013 project that requires the user to have external files for the application to work.

I was told there was a way to include that file in the application and "extract" it if needed but not seeing anything on its use.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under the "My Project" folder in the Solution Explorer, you will find a Resources.resx file. Double-clicking on it will bring up the Resources editor.

Under the `Add Resource` button, you will see `Add existing file`

Once added to the resources, the file can be accessed like this:

```
My.Resources.FileName
```

or, if you want to save it back to file:

```
File.WriteAllBytes("C:\Path\To\FileName.extension", My.Resources.FileName)
```